# Adding a new line in a part of an equation

Tags: equations, line-breaking, subequations

I am facing problem in writing the `\underset` part of the `\sum` of the following equation (i.e. `path($u^{(\pi_1)},u^{(\pi_2)},\dots,u^{(\pi_t)}$), from $\pi_1=j$ to $\pi_t=n$}`)
[image: sample equation]

I want it to break in two lines as it is in the original equation, but I can't get it work. I have tried `align`, `multlined` and `split`, but they seem to work only for the complete equation, but not for the inner part of an equation.

Settings for the environment is below:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myequation}{%
    \begin{equation}
    \scalebox{1.25}{$\BODY$}
    \end{equation}
    }

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

And the Latex code for the equation is:

```
\begin{myequation}
\frac{\partial u^{(n)}}{\partial u^{(j)}}=\underset{\textnormal{path($u^{(\pi_1)},u^{(\pi_2)},\dots,u^{(\pi_t)}$), from $\pi_1=j$ to $\pi_t=n$}}{\sum}\underset{k=2}{\overset{t}{\prod}}\frac{\partial u^{(\pi_k)}}{\partial u^{(\pi_{k-1})}}
\end{myequation}
```

Please help me get the format correct as per the provided equation (I need to copy the equation exactly as shown).

If this is a similar question to any already asked, please tell me the link as I was not able to find it.

Your help will be great!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In future please instead of code sniped provide complete small document beginning with `\documantclas{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` which exhibit your problem. Help us to help you!

Comment: @Zarko, sure, I will take care of that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use standard `amsmath` environments and math macro `substack`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}%

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u^{(n)}}
     {\partial u^{(j)}}
    = \sum_{\substack{\text{path }(u^{(\pi_1)},u^{(\pi_2)},\dots,u^{(\pi_t)}),\\ 
                      \text{from }\pi_1=j \text{ to }\pi_t=n}}
        \quad
        \prod_{k=2}^{t} \frac{\partial u^{(\pi_k)}}
                             {\partial u^{(\pi_{k-1})}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Zarko. It works with the standard `asmath` environment as you suggested. But I need a workaround as I require the equation to scale bigger than they are in the standard environment by 1.25, any suggestions there?
Can I still do it without creating a new environment?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
\begin{myequation}
\frac{\partial u^{(n)}}{\partial u^{(j)}}=\sum_{\substack{\text{path }(u^{(\pi_1)},u^{(\pi_2)},\dots,u^{(\pi_t)}),\\ \text{from } \pi_1=j\text{ to } \pi_t=n$} \prod_{k=2}^{t}\frac{\partial u^{(\pi_k)}}{\partial u^{(\pi_{k-1})}}
\end{myequation}
```